# How can I redefine a method before it exists?

Tags: ruby, homebrew, monkeypatching

In homebrew on OS X, there's a `DownloadStrategyDetector` class, I'm making a tap and need to override a couple methods on this class to add additional download strategies (they're very niche so won't be accepted into core).

I tried simply redefining (see below) the class above my `Formula` class in an attempt to override the default definition, however the regular version of the class is still used.

```
class DownloadStrategyDetector
  def self.detect_from_url(url)
    # ...
  end

  def self.detect_from_symbol(symbol)
    # ...
  end
end
```

Is there a way to force all uses of a class to a particular definition? This is the backtrace from the call that winds up using the default definition of the class.

My code is in `tester.rb` and that indirectly calls `resource.rb` which loads `download_strategy.rb` which overrides my definition of `DownloadStrategyDetector`.

backtrace:

```
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/download_strategy.rb:963:in `detect_from_symbol'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/download_strategy.rb:916:in `detect'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:144:in `url'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb:62:in `url'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:1666:in `url'
/Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Ruby/homebrew-core/formula/tester.rb:68:in `<class:Tester>'
/Users/camdennarzt/Developer/Ruby/homebrew-core/formula/tester.rb:63:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:25:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:25:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:42:in `load_formula_from_path'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:91:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:82:in `klass'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:78:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:215:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:29:in `block in resolved_formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:27:in `map'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:27:in `resolved_formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/reinstall.rb:10:in `reinstall'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:87:in `<main>'
```

I tried another strategy as well, where I added a hook to my `DownloadStrategyDetector` class like this, and tried to swap the methods using aliases:

```
class DownloadStrategyDetector
  def self.singleton_method_added(name)
    puts name
    alias_method :detect_from_url, :detect_from_url_2 if name == :detect_from_url
    alias_method :detect_from_symbol, :detect_from_symbol_2 if name == :detect_from_symbol
  end

  def self.detect_from_url_2(url)
    # ...
  end

  def self.detect_from_symbol_2(symbol)
    # ...
  end
end
```

but it only printed the following, as if the class was never reopened:

```
singleton_method_added
detect_from_url_2
detect_from_symbol_2
```

Comment: Have you tried prepending a module to that class?

Comment: Just tried that, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Then I suppose your patch is not loaded.

Comment: Do you require your monkey patch?

Comment: @farhatmihalko not explicitly, as it's in code that gets required by the rest of the codebase. Ie: it's in `tester.rb`, which as you can see gets included already. And since I need this to work with an unmodified homebrew, I can't just require it where I want to make the change (or I'd just edit that file directly and be done)

Comment: @CamdenNarzt Do you use only resource.rb? Maybe you patch `url` method in resource.rb?

Comment: I found a way to not have to add a download strategy, so I no longer NEED an answer to this. It'd still be somewhat interesting to know of a way to make this work though.